# How to call the CMS(Content Managment System) function in javascript inside the php file

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system

In my simple CMS webpage, i try to call the CMS function in javascript. but i can't.
This is my code in script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit()
{ 
     obj->display_edit(); 
}
</script>
```

`display_edit()` is the funtion in CMS.
`obj` is the object for the class created in CMS.

And i tried to call this function using javascript. Is there any possible way is available to do this action?

Comment: You can’t call server-side PHP functions in client-side JavaScript.

Comment: You can use ajax request for call some PHP script with functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might be trying to call a PHP function within a script tag which will not work. For example in Wordpress you would use a template tag: `<?php get_title() ?>`.

Script tags are only for javascript.

If you can provide the CMS your using I could be more specific.

Comment: From your answer i can access the function inside the same file.But i need to access the function `display_edit()` from another PHP file with object  `obj` of the class which is containing the particular function

Comment: Could you provide the CMS framework you are using? Or is this a CMS you created yourself in PHP?

Comment: Nothing like that..You can refer this link [Build your first simple CMS](https://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms)